# What does the Eclipse TextMate themes menu do?

Tags: eclipse

In *Window > Preferences > TextMate > Theme* there's the ability to add and remove TextMate themes.

Does this mean that Eclipse supports TextMate themes, and if it does, how do I apply one of the themes?

Here's a screenshot of the menu:

[image: out put picture]

Comment: See https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.tm4e

Comment: I think it's a right-click in the Generic Text Editor to switch themes, but that preference page is ignoring all sorts of interface guidelines, plus it doesn't supply any sample text to see how it's colored by the themes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can add here **CSS files** used for **syntax coloring** for languages and formats that are based on a TextMate grammar: see preferences *Language Servers* for the supported languages/formats (there can be  language/format support only for syntax coloring via TextMate grammar, but - as far as I know - all built-in languages/formats support code completion, etc. via language servers). See the [**built-in themes**](https://github.com/eclipse/tm4e/tree/master/org.eclipse.tm4e.ui/themes) which can be used to create your own theme.

A file with syntax coloring via a TextMate grammar has to be opened in the ***Generic Text Editor***: choose a theme via **right-click** and ***Switch to Theme...***.

Please note, a TextMate grammar for syntax coloring of a specific file format can currently be added, as far as I know, only via an Eclipse plugin.